# Filter rows within an analytical function - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I need to filter rows within an analytical function (for example: lag). 
Is there a way to do that efficiently **without sub-query** (It is a very large table)?

This is the table:

[image]

And the expected result should look like the following:

[image]

Comment: Please show your query *with the analytic function*.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typical use of analytic functions.  In this case, I think a cumulative `max()` seems appropriate:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when is_valid = 1 then date end) over 
           (partition by client_id
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
           ) as last_valid_session
from t;
```

It is hard to think of a more concise way to implement this logic, although `lag()` or `last_value()` could also be used:

```
select t.*,
       lag(case when is_valid = 1 then date end ignore nulls) over 
           (partition by client_id
            order by date
           ) as last_valid_session
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAG` with `IGNORE NULLS` and a `CASE` expression to filter for only valid dates:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( session_id, client_id, is_valid, "DATE" ) AS
SELECT  1, 11, 0, DATE '2018-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 22, 1, DATE '2018-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 33, 0, DATE '2018-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 11, 1, DATE '2018-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 22, 0, DATE '2018-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 33, 1, DATE '2018-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 11, 0, DATE '2018-01-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 22, 1, DATE '2018-01-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 33, 0, DATE '2018-01-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 11, 1, DATE '2018-01-10' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       LAG( CASE is_valid WHEN 1 THEN "DATE" END )
         IGNORE NULLS
         OVER ( PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY "DATE" )
         AS last_valid_session
FROM   test_data t
ORDER BY session_id
```

**Output**:

> ```
> SESSION_ID | CLIENT_ID | IS_VALID | DATE      | LAST_VALID_SESSION
> ---------: | --------: | -------: | :-------- | :-----------------
>          1 |        11 |        0 | 01-JAN-18 | null              
>          2 |        22 |        1 | 02-JAN-18 | null              
>          3 |        33 |        0 | 03-JAN-18 | null              
>          4 |        11 |        1 | 04-JAN-18 | null              
>          5 |        22 |        0 | 05-JAN-18 | 02-JAN-18         
>          6 |        33 |        1 | 06-JAN-18 | null              
>          7 |        11 |        0 | 07-JAN-18 | 04-JAN-18         
>          8 |        22 |        1 | 08-JAN-18 | 02-JAN-18         
>          9 |        33 |        0 | 09-JAN-18 | 06-JAN-18         
>         10 |        11 |        1 | 10-JAN-18 | 04-JAN-18
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=510387cc418b44c9d30286629cdc80d9)*